# Wordpress get_permalink() has different behavior in admin than on page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress theme using WPML and I have pages translated from English to Chinese.

I'm trying to code the *English/Chinese* link to change language on the page, but the get_permalink() function returns the wrong values. If I'm on the English pages, it returns only the English page link and vice versa on the Chinese pages.

Say post #10 is my English home page and #120 the translated Chinese page, when I'm on the English home page and I echo get_permalink(10) or get_permalink(120), I get the same URL, the English page's URL. If I do that on the Chinese version of the page, both snippets return the Chinese page's URL.

I figured it had to be WPML that didn't work correctly or something weird with the get_permalink() function, but it's not! Because, on the wp-admin pages, get_permalink() works exactly as expected. So I'm a little lost... **How can get_permalink() have a different behaviour when I'm in an wp-admin context than when I'm in a page context?**

Comment: get_page_link() has the same problem.

Comment: need to show code, its not the default code, also show urls

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to get the permalink of a custom post, but before `register_post_type()` was being called.  The solution was to rearrange the priorities of my handlers to ensure the custom post type was registered before calling `get_permalink()`.